# change xml on layout view android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android.  I wanna create something like this.   two buttons to go   "Next" and "Previous" content. middle content should be changed  by  pressing  "Next" & "Previous" buttons.   I think     I can use fragments for this.  but how to just change only middle area of a layout without changing whole layout.

thank you

[image]

Comment: Try to use ViewPager : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Actually if you are going to only change the content (text, etc.) you can do it in a single layout, by using setter methods of the middle layout at each button press. When you press next, use setText for the new content.

Comment: Thanx. I like to add both answers as "Answers"  but for some reason. I cant mark  those as answers.  your answers display to me as comments. there is no checkmarks  to mark  as answers. sorry about that.